# Rename files to lowercase in Powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, recursive-descent

I am trying to rename a bunch of files recursively using Powershell 2.0. The directory structure looks like this:

```
Leaflets
+ HTML
  - File1
  - File2
  ...
+ HTMLICONS
  + IMAGES
    - Image1
    - Image2
  - File1
  - File2
  ...
+ RTF
  - File1
  - File2
  ...
+ SGML
  - File1
  - File2
  ...
```

I am using the following command:

```
get-childitem Leaflets -recurse | rename -newname { $_.name.ToLower() }
```

and it seems to rename the files, but complains about the subdirectories:

```
Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
```

I reload the data monthly using robocopy, but the directories do not change, so I can rename them by hand. Is there any way to get `get-children` to skip the subdirectories (like `find Leaflets -type f ...`)?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** It appears that the problem is with files that are already all lower case. I tried changing the command to:

```
get-childitem Leaflets -recurse | if ($_.name -ne $_name.ToLower()) rename -newname { $_.name.ToLower() }
```

but now Powershell complains that `if` is not a cmdlet, function, etc.
Can I pipe the output of `get-childitem` to an `if` statement?

**UPDATE 2**: This works:

```
$files=get-childitem Leaflets -recurse
foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($file.name -ne $file.name.ToLower())
    {
        rename -newname { $_.name.ToLower() }
    }
}
```

Comment: In PowerShell 7 at least, `Rename-Item` doesn't error out if the new name is the same as the old name. I'm not sure which version this behavior changed in though. But your first attempt piping `gci` to `rename-item` works now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Even though you have already posted your own answer, here is a variation:

```
dir Leaflets -r | % { if ($_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower()) { ren $_.FullName $_.Name.ToLower() } }
```

Some points:

- **dir** is an alias for **Get-ChildItem** (and -r is short for -Recurse).
- **%** is an alias for **ForEach-Object**.
- **-cne** is a case-sensitive comparison. **-ne** ignores case differences.
- **$_** is how you reference the current item in the ForEach-Object loop.
- **ren** is an alias for **Rename-Item**.
- **FullName** is probably preferred as it ensures you will be touching the right file.

If you wanted to excludes directories from being renamed, you could include something like:

```
if ((! $_.IsPsContainer) -and $_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower()) { ... }
```

Hopefully this is helpful in continuing to learn and explore PowerShell.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this works for renaming files but not directories.  
For directories, you'll need to do 2 rename operations. See [here](https://til.secretgeek.net/powershell/Rename_to_lower_case.html) for an example.

Answer (score 20):

Keep in mind that you can pipe directly to Rename-Item and use Scriptblocks with the -`NewName` parameter (because it also accepts pipeline input) to simplify this task:

```
Get-ChildItem -r | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
                   Rename-Item -NewName {$_.FullName.ToLower()}
```

and with aliases:

```
gci -r | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | rni -New {$_.FullName.ToLower()}
```

Comment: Thanks. And to change file names we can use this : 
gci . -recurse -force | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | rni -New {$_.Name.replace("aaa","bbb")}

Answer (score 4):

There are many issues with the previous given answers due to the nature of how `Rename-Item`, Piping, Looping and the Windows Filesystem works. Unfortunatly the the most simple (not using aliases for readability here) solution I found to **rename all files and folders** inside of a given folder to lower-case is this one:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "/Path/To/You/Folder" -Recurse | Where{ $_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower() } | ForEach-Object { $tn="$($_.Name)-temp"; $tfn="$($_.FullName)-temp"; $nn=$_.Name.ToLower(); Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $tn; Rename-Item -Path $tfn -NewName $nn -Force; Write-Host "New Name: $($nn)";}
```

Comment: I used this to rename a few million files - one catch is it doesn't handle files with a bracket eg: '[' or ']' . I think something [here](https://superuser.com/questions/212808/powershell-bug-in-copy-move-rename-when-filename-contains-square-bracket-charac) has a solution. 

I didn't attempt to fix because I have a post work around and this took care of most issues.

Comment: You might also need the folders lower cased - something like this can be run from the root of where you are working:

```
    #Get the directories / sub directories and rename to lowercase
    
    Get-ChildItem -recurse| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Name -CMatch "[A-Z]" } | %{
    $NName = $_.Name.ToLower()
    
    #Set temporary name to enable rename to the same name; Windows is not case sensitive
    
    $TempItem = Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "x$NName" -PassThru
    Rename-Item -Path $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NName
    
    }
```

Comment: Should use Rename-Item -LiteralPath instead of -Path as some file types are not supported (like brackets otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

You need to temporarily rename them to something else then name them back all lower case.

```
$items = get-childitem -Directory -Recurse

foreach ($item in $items)
{

   if ($item.name -eq $item.name.ToLower())
   {    

       $temp = $item.FullName.ToLower() + "_"
       $name = $item.FullName.ToLower()
       ren $name $temp

       ren $temp $name
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

slight tweak on this, if you only want to update the names of files of a particular type try this:

```
get-childitem *.jpg | foreach { if ($_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower()) { ren $_.FullName $_.Name.ToLower() } }
```

this will only lowercase the jpg files within your folder and ignore the rest

Answer (score 1):

for everyone who is following this thread; the following line can also be used to lower both files and directories.

```
Get-ChildItem -r  | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToLower().Insert(0,'_') } -PassThru |  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(1) }
```

Main post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559621/4165074

Answer (score 0):

It's more idomatic in PowerShell to use `where` instead of `if` in a pipeline:

```
gci -Recurse Leaflets | 
    ? { $_.Name -ne $_.Name.ToLower()) } | 
    % { ren -NewName $_.Name.ToLower() }
```

Answer (score 0):

A small but important correction to the answer from Jay Bazuzi. The `-cne` (case sensitive not equal) operator must be used if the where-part should return anything.

Additionally I found that the Path parameter needed to be present. This version worked in my setup:

```
gci -Recurse | 
    ? { $_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower() } | 
    % { ren $_.Name -NewName $_.Name.Tolower()  }
```

Comment: did you test your code on an uppercase folder?
The actual issue is that `rename-item` throws an error because it considers uppercase==lower internally.

Answer (score 0):

Modified to work with [] brackets in the name or other unsupported chars and will handle the directories too (or you can leave that out). I pieced this together from various places.

Should be able to put this in a file, then navigate to the target dir and run it from there.

```
#Get the directories / sub directories and rename to lowercase 
Get-ChildItem -recurse| ?{ $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Name -CMatch "[A-Z]" } | %{ 
$NName = $_.Name.ToLower() 
#Set temporary name to enable rename to the same name; Windows is not case sensitive 
$TempItem = Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName "x$NName" -PassThru Rename-Item -LiteralPath $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NName }

#Now handle all the files
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath . -Recurse | Where{ $_.Name -cne $_.Name.ToLower() } | ForEach-Object { 
$tn="$($_.Name)-temp"; $tfn="$($_.FullName)-temp"; 
$nn=$_.Name.ToLower(); 
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $tn; 
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $tfn -NewName $nn -Force; 
Write-Host "New Name: $($nn)";
}
```