# How can I modify this PowerShell script to include changing directory names to lower?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rename all files and directories to lower and I found a powershell script here: [Rename files to lowercase in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822745/rename-files-to-lowercase-in-powershell)

My favorite answer is the following because it is the cleanest and most concise answer. However, it does not include directory names and I don't have enough rep yet to respond to the comment

```
Get-ChildItem -r | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.FullName.ToLower() }
```

I don't know PowerShell and I don't intend to become proficient, please skip all the details I'm just looking for code to rename all my files and directories to lower and I don't need to know anything about how it works. I don't like the following solution because 1, it is too wordy and 2, it only does directory names and not file names.

```
Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -And $_.Name -CMatch "[A-Z]" } |
ForEach-Object {
    $NName = $_.Name.ToLowerInvariant()

    # Set temporary name to enable rename to the same name; Windows is not case sensitive
    $TempItem = Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "x$NName" -PassThru

    Rename-Item -Path $TempItem.FullName -NewName $NName
}
```

I want one clean command to rename files and directories, similar to the first example, please

---

when i first wrote this, i just wanted to open powershell and paste a command. in hindsight, that is not most efficient way either. so i ended up saving each script (one for files, one for folders) into one .ps1 file that you put in whatever directory you want to lower, then right-click and "run with powershell" and it will rename all files and subdirectories

the script looks like this:

```
# files to lower
Get-ChildItem -r | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.FullName.ToLower() }

# folders to lower
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
Get-ChildItem . -rec -dir |
ForEach-Object { $fso.MoveFolder($_.fullname, $_.Fullname.ToLower()) }
```

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i just tested and i'm getting IO error "Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different."

Comment: Well, I deleted my answer since it only works on Linux due to the OS case sensitivity. This is also relevant https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12483, _`[Directory]::Move()` having the same behavior_ hence why we see this in PS seems like a great excuse to me. You probably are better of __using `ren` from CMD__ or for PS, rename the folder to a temporary name and rename back to lowercase which is honestly awful (this is what your second snippet is doing....)

Comment: no worries bro thanks for the follow up the git issue you linked explains what's happening well. it's just for my personal preference to have lower case and is not urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you mentioned on your provided code, Windows is not a case sensitive OS, so you need to rename the directories to a  temp name (for example insert a character after lowering it) then rename it again (by removing the inserted character)

i modified your line as follow to be able to lower both directories and files, please give it a try

```
Get-ChildItem -r  | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.ToLower().Insert(0,'_') } -PassThru |  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Substring(1) }
```

Comment: works for me on windows, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome Kyle